# Selenium can't find a tag

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

Chrome dev tool:
[image]
I cannot grab the xmp tag or class "note" getting error

I tried these

```
    # status = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".msgdiv")
    status = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "note")
```

Comment: Can you please share your source code with the URL  you want to scrap. It will be helpful for us to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the element by id:

```
div = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'msgDiv')
status = div.get_attribute('innerText')
```